# executing a code of webservice in another child process in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I need an understanding and code architecture of how to run a time consuming web service in a separate child process. Is it good to run in a separate child process such kind of web service which will run longer. The web service will receive a pay load of upto like 2000 nested json objects, numbers could be less or more, and it will fetch the data and insert into the database. Below is just the code snippet just to give an idea.

```
router.post('/longRunningWebservice', function (req, res) {
    //for loop to iterate 2000 json objects 
    //it has some queries to insert data
    //it has some if conditions to check
    //and finally res.send()
});
```

I need to understand and want to run the the code in a separate child process to make it more scalable, and also utilize the other cores.

Answer (score 0):

1. fork some workers at the begining of the code
2. in your code write seperate worker tasks and master tasks 'if (cluster.isMaster) {...} else {...}'
3. send the data which needs to be processed to the worker with IPC messaging or redis pub/sub messaging, after the worker processed the data it can send it back to the master which handles the response.

other notes:

- you can set multiple workers and determine which is busy and which is not
- redis pub/sub if better then IPC cuz with IPC you can only communicate with master - worker, with redis pub/sub you can communicate with master - worker and worker - worker.
- best practice is to setup a master which only forks workers and refork them if they die cuz of an error or something, you can also create 1 worker which handles http requests and 3 workers which processes data eg. if you have 4 processor cores.

additional approach:
Fork workers with all the same tasks (handle http and data processing), cluster will automatically handle load ballance and instead of for loop create a recursive function which process a single json object then call itself with setimmediate so the data processing will not block event loop and a single worker can handle multiple requests. easy way

Comment: Kailniris, Thankyou for the explanation, can you please provide some example like how to fork some workers in a webservice, and write separate workers task or which you have stated in your third point "you can also create 1 worker which handles http requests and 3 workers which processes data eg. if you have 4 processor cores", any example will give me more clear picture. Thankyou

Comment: i will, but keep in mind its a bit overcomplicated approach and without redis, its even more complicated, do you consider using redis or simply IPC messaging?

Comment: I have considerd using redis but not at this stage, I am very much new to redis and IPC and in this clustering/forking. It would be nice if you could provide me with an example. Thankyou once again :)

Comment: Kailniris one more thing, does processing of a data in a for loop really blocks the event loop? what if I send multiple requests will it not work?

Comment: well in asynchronous javascript environment especially in node.js doing something not I/O will block the event loop. like doing something like array.push('asd') will block the event loop for very small amount of time you won't notice but if you create a for loop or any kind of loop which will do array.push('asd') lots of time i mean thousand of billions of times the app basically will freeze busy doing the foor loop. In node.js this will basicaly block all I/O so all the request will time out. In client no user interaction or other javascript will work.

Comment: so no, no multiple request can work parallal if you use sync functions like JSON.parse like in your example. JSON.parse is pretty fast in V8 but iterate over 2000 json objects can be time consuming.
This does not mean loops are inherited bad you just have to be careful how much data you process with it. In large data sets instead of loops you can use recursive function , each function called with setImidiate so each function will be put after the next event loop IO. It will be slower but will not block the event loop so multiple request can be processed simultaniously

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114965/discussion-between-jn-newbie-and-kailniris).